# Removes the first character of the duplicate characters in the string

Tags: c#, string, uwp

I have a string `string x = "1b:2c:3a:4d:1c:2b"`

I want if there are duplicate numbers, the first number and the letter behind it are removed and replaced with the same last letter and number. Then it becomes `string y = "1c:2b:3a:4d"`.

How to apply it?

Comment: To phrase it differently you want for every number only the last character mentioned in the string named and it should be "sorted" by number?

Comment: Can the numbers be more than a single digit?

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
var result = x.Split(':').GroupBy(s => s[0]).Select(g => g.Last());
string y = string.Join(":", result); // "1c:2b:3a:4d"
```

Short explanation: first i split by `:` to get a `string[]` with all tokens, these are then grouped by the first character which is the digit. I take the last of each group, so from duplicate numbers it's taking the last one and fron non-duplicates there is only one. Finally `Join` puts all together.